# Registry editor windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

I have a question regarding Windows Registry editor. I have disabled the settings window, wallpaper change and control panel via several DWORDs in the Windows Registry.

This works just fine in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, which disables the aforementioned features for all the PC users, including the admin. Meaning that when in the admin account, I have to disable the DWORDs in order to gain access again to the control panel (as an example).

Setting the same DWORDs in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER does not work. I wonder why. The way I see it is it either disables the features for all users or enables them for everyone. Using HKEY_CURRENT_USER to disable them for a specific user is not working.

Did I misunderstand the usage of HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry?

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the programmer for which registry keys to read.  It is as simple as that.  This is not done magically by the registry API.

When I write code to read the registry, I have to check one.. if not exist.. check the other.. if not exist.. use a default.

IF you put the keys in the same spot under HKEY_CURRENT_USER and they didn't work, then the windows explorer (desktop) isn't reading them.  I am betting that this is by design having to do with permissions.

I am guessing the reasons are:

1. ANYONE running as the current user (even malware) can modify the current user's HKEY_CURRENT_USER branch.  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE requires admin.
2. If you are on a windows domain, then the domain admin might want to control these things without giving you the ability to change them.  The group policy editor might give you a way but I don't know what that might be.

***You could (in theory) do a work around for this by:***

1. Change the permisssions for the keys you are trying to modify in LOCAL_MACHINE so the user could modify them without escalating privileges (bad idea)
2. Set a startup task to set the registry keys for each user when they log in.  It would load a custom .reg file from each users local profile directory (also bad idea)

This would fall on it's head if more than one user were logged in at the same time.